# No matter how much I pour over my code, I can't figure out how to rectify my import cycle. (Golang)

Tags: windows, go, bitcoin

I've spent hours pouring over multiple threads looking for solutions but I'm struggling with even being able to identify the issue. I'm very,very new to Go, but I understand that it's not permitted to have import cycles, and I understand that means that package a is relying on package b and vise versa. Here is the output I am getting,

```
C:\Windows\System32\src\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum>go install -v
import cycle not allowed
package .
    imports errors
    imports runtime
    imports runtime/internal/atomic
    imports unsafe
    imports runtime
import cycle not allowed
package .
    imports github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types
    imports github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/vm
    imports github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto
    imports github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/ecies
    imports github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/secp256k1
    imports runtime/cgo
    imports runtime/cgo
```

can someone PLEASE help me at least figure out what I'm looking for in order to fix it :/

Thanks all in advance

Comment: the question is why you set your  gopath in System32?

Comment: You are looking for reciprocal imports in different packages.
For example, in package "packageA" you have 
import "github.com/foo/packageB"

and in package "packageB" you have
import "github.com/foo/packageA".

To solve need to see your code.

Comment: @AngeloAngeles I was following a guide and just did as it said. Should it not go through System32?

Comment: @drewh784 usually you want to put it in your user profile.

Answer (score 0):

To install this repo, you don't need to use `get install` from the root directory of the project. Instead you should use `make geth`

For information how the installation process works you can read the Makefile of go-etherenum:

- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/Makefile

For details installation instuction for Mac/Linux/Windows follow this guide:

- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Ethereum

Comment: those are the instructions which I was following, so I'm still not sure what to do @Aminadav

Comment: So please edit the question, so what you tried and the response. You don't need to use `go install` as you mention